# How can I load large number of items from Firebase to RecyclerView?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I'm looking for an efficient approach to retrieve and display over 500 sets of data from Firestore in my RecyclerView. Each data set comprises three Strings and a storage reference (e.g., `tools/imageName.jpg` and I also used Glide for image display)

Initially, I attempted to retrieve all 500+ data sets from Firestore at once and display them immediately in my RecyclerView. To manage the delay, I implemented a loading dialog until the data retrieval and display were complete. However, this approach took too much time, particularly during the data retrieval phase. The reason behind retrieving all values at once is due to the search functionality I implemented for my RecyclerView. I wanted to load all the data first to facilitate the search process.

I'm seeking advice on more efficient methods that won't consume as much time. Are there alternative approaches or best practices for handling large datasets from Firestore in a RecyclerView?

Comment: 500 documents that contai 3 string fields and a url sounds like a tiny amount of data and should load almost instantly with low memory impact. While you can use pagination, it's such a small amount of data that shouldn't have any impact. I would look to your code, internet connection or something else causing the delays. However without more info, that's just a guess. Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If you consider trying to use [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose), then I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-implement-pagination-in-firestore-using-jetpack-compose-76b4c0b5acd5) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestorePaginationJetpackCompose).

Comment: @Jay I appreciate your input! Just wanted to give you an update – I completed the app, and though I initially estimated 500 documents, it ended up being over 2000 due to some changes. With this increase, loading all the documents at once takes around 5 to 10 seconds, provided the device has a decent internet connection, though I'm not sure if that time is fast or slow given the number of documents that I'm retrieving. Thanks again for your feedback!

Comment: That's pretty slow. Firebase is blisteringly fast; 2000 records of that size should load in something like... 1-2s or less given a decent modern internet connection. There's a pretty good answer below using Pagination (and highly scalable), but it doesn't sound like this is a large about of data so you should not be seeing that kind of delay. But... it depends on the actual amount of data and what's being done with it - we can't see your code so only you know that part.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Pagination -

Instead of fetching the entire dataset at once, implement pagination to load a limited set of items (i.e. 20 items on each page)initially and load more as the user scrolls. Firestore provides pagination support through query cursors. This way, you only fetch the data you need, reducing the initial loading time. Below code snippet will help.

Modify your Firestore query to include pagination. Use the **limit** method to retrieve a limited number of documents in each query. Also, use **startAfter** to start the next query after the last document from the previous query.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

    val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
    val lastVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()

    if (lastVisibleItemPosition == adapter.itemCount - 1) {
        // Load more data
        loadMoreData()
    }
}})
```

In the loadMoreData function, perform the next Firestore query with startAfter and update the adapter. Then all set.